# Wordpress Query about posting a private blog

Tags: wordpress

I want to ask a simple question about wordpress.My question is when i make a post private in my website it appears with the word "Private" as a title.Can anyone resolve this?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the label in the title using two filters

[private_title_format](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/private_title_format)

[protected_title_format](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/protected_title_format/)

You need to add this code in your theme functions.php file or using a plugin.

```
function tm_private_protected_from_titles( $format ) {
    return '%s';
}
add_filter( 'private_title_format',  'tm_private_protected_from_titles' );
add_filter( 'protected_title_format',  'tm_private_protected_from_titles' );
```

Comment: Where i have to put this code..I mean there are lots of coding in the function.php file

Answer (score 0):

private post will display in front end if you are login with admin other wise private post will never on front end. User will not able to see your private posts.If you remove it from private then the word "Private" will also removed

Comment: i want my post to be private.Is there any way that i can remove the word "Private" that is appearing as title.This error occur suddenly and i just not able to resolve it.

Comment: This will help you: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-remove-private-from-private-pages

Comment: can you mark it correct if you think I will help you